# Detect hung state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redis, bull

I am working for a application which is a version control system. Currently there are 5 servers which can be deployed and we have to keep monitoring the status while deployment(active,completed,hung,failed),
so how can I check hung state of any of the worker? .
I am using bulljs for monitoring and communicating to redis queue
Tech stack used:
React , nodejs, redis queue, bull monitor
**Note: we can't set threshold time or memory consumption as there can be different application which can take various time and memory for deployment or build.**

I have tried many ways :

1. Using stall event to check when job is stalled
2. Used os module to check memory consumption and set threshold

Above solutions are not approved as we can't set manually any threshold because there can be multiple applications which deploys their code which can veried on memory consumption and time